# Pl/sql bad bind error

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g

Can someone help me with the code below:

1. I'm not sure why it throws an error
2. `RETURN    (salary > min_sal) &      (salary <=Max sal)`  - are these valid?

When I run the code I get a `PLS 00049 BAD BIND error`

```
Create or REPLACE FUNCTION sal_ok(SALARY number, jobgrade NUMBER)
RETURN BOOLEAN AS
BEGIN
SELECT losal, hisal INTO :min_sal, :max_sal FROM salgrade
WHERE grade = jobgrade;
RETURN (salary >=min_sal) AND  (salary <=Max sal);
END sal_ok;
/
```

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: What are you trying to return here?

Comment: Where are `min_sal` and `max_sal` declared.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting bad bind error is because you have not declared `min_sal` and `max_sal` variables anywhere in your function.

Do as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sal_ok (salary NUMBER, jobgrade NUMBER)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
min_sal number;
max_sal number;
BEGIN
    SELECT  losal, hisal
      INTO  min_sal, max_sal
      FROM  salgrade
     WHERE  grade = jobgrade;

    RETURN (salary >= min_sal) AND (salary <= max_sal); -- not sure about this line as   I am not sure what you would want to return
END sal_ok;
/
```

This will get rid of your bad bind error.

Regarding your return statement, I am not sure what you would want to return from your function.

Comment: he wants to return whether the salary is ok, hence the binary calculation at the end. I don't remember if pl/sql allows it as it stands in the code right now. It should, but i've been surprised many times by some huge lacks around booleans in this language. If so, just insert the calculation within the sql itself, and select .. into .. booleanvariable, and then return the variable. Another good idea would be to return a number instead, since boolean is not an Oracle native sql type and cannot be used outside pl/sql.

Comment: @Sebas yes boolean has that limitation of cannot being used outside plsql. OP should return a number instead.